# Why doesn't argument dependent lookup work with default arguments?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup, default-arguments

I wrote the following code half expecting the default argument to trigger ADL. It doesn't (I got a compiler error instead).
Are explicit arguments required to trigger ADL?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace sheldon
{
    enum FLAG{ USA , UK , EU };

    void fun( FLAG f = USA )
    {
        std::cout << "Fun with flags!" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    fun();  // Does not compile
    // fun( sheldon::USA ); // compiles
}
```

Comment: Well... you can't trigger ADL without arguments.  To clarify, "arguments" refer to the actual values/references passed when a function is invoked, as opposed to "parameters" which are the names/types that a function specifies in its declaration.

Comment: @JohnKugelman thank you kindly, and done.

Comment: ADL standards for Argument Dependent Lookup. It's all in the name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADL only works with the arguments you give it, otherwise things would be really horrible, namespaces would become useless in isolating their contents.
Think what would happen if you had this as well:

```
namespace fun {
    struct tag {};
    void fun(tag = {})
    {
        std::cout << "Fun with tags!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Shall we have fun with flags or tags?

Comment: Whoa `fun::fun ()` actually complies! ... BTW did you mean to write `namespace sheldon` instead of `namespace fun`?

Comment: No. It should demonstrate that you drown in cross-namespace conflicts if ADL worked with default arguments too.

Comment: Ah ... I see. If ADL worked in the manner I supposed. The compiler would be free to choose any `fun()` in any namespace.

Comment: Chose this answer because it showed the chaos that would otherwise result.

Answer (score 3):

When the compiler encounters a function call expression, it first builds an overload set of possible functions to call, and then performs overload resolution. ADL is part of the overload set generation.
Now, when coming to this statement:

```
fun();
```

First, it looks in the global namespace for possible overloads. And it finds none.
Then it does ADL based on the arguments *passed*, but you didn't pass any arguments.
The overload set is therefore empty.

Answer (score 2):

The following function invocation:

```
fun();
```

Contains no arguments, so there's no way it could trigger argument-dependent lookup.

To clarify, "arguments" refer to the actual values/references passed when a function is invoked, as opposed to "parameters" which are the names/types that a function specifies in its declaration.

Comment: You make a very interesting point. But a "default value" (let's call it that) is neither a name nor a type. I am taking you literally.

Comment: @Olumide: correct, but I don't really consider the default value to be encompassed by the definition of "parameter".  In this example's case, the type is `FLAG`, the name is `f`.  The default value is a piece of information that complements the parameter but is not part of it. I'm going mostly from memory, though, and I'd have to check the language specification to make sure my terminology matches up.

Comment: "You don't really consider"? ... (I don't wish to be mean but) surely such matters are not left to individual opinion.